# How do I get Whatsapp 'Context' field from Twilio API?

Tags: twilio

In the official Whatsapp Business API documentation, there's a 'context' field that indicates when a user is replying to a message.

How do get this field from the Twilio API?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently the Twilio API does not support the context field with information about message replies. The [parameters that Twilio does support are listed in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters) and are `ProfileName`, `WaId` (WhatsApp ID, typically a phone number), `Forwarded`, `FrequentlyForwarded`, `ButtonText` (if using quick reply buttons), and, when receiving location messages, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Address`, and `Label`.

These parameters are updated as we increase our support for the WhatsApp API, so check back regularly or keep an eye on [the changelog](https://www.twilio.com/changelog?product=programmable-messaging) for updates.